# Javascript not updating text within a div

Tags: javascript

I must be daft, but the javascript is not changing the containing div text as I would expect once the div is clicked:

```
favourite.onclick = function() {     
        loadXMLDoc('indexFavourite'); 
        var linkclass = favourite.className;
        if(linkclass == 'favouriteOption')
            favourite.className = 'favouriteOptionActive',
            favourite.className.update("New text");
        else
            favourite.className = 'favouriteOption';
}
```

Comment: what is favourite, what does loadXMLDoc do - all you have posted here is a change of className. What is .update? Some framework?

Comment: so what do you want ??

Comment: What is `favourite.className.update()` supposed to achieve?

Comment: but you are changing the className and not the divs text

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is way off, missing bracket and whatnot

```
favourite.onclick = function() {     
  loadXMLDoc('indexFavourite'); 
  var linkclass = favourite.className;
  if(linkclass == 'favouriteOption') {
    favourite.className = 'favouriteOptionActive',
    favourite.innerHTML="New text";
  }
  else {
    favourite.className = 'favouriteOption';
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is what I tried to say.  Unknowingly I made a mistake, so deleted my answer for editing.  However you made it with complete code. Nice one

Comment: ahh, thats the one! Perfecto dude!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is changing the class of a div (probably). And even this is kinda wrong. I mean

```
favourite.className = 'favouriteOptionActive',
favourite.className.update("New text");
```

should actually produce an error, because the string *favouriteOptionActive* doesn't have a method update. It could have only if you patch the String.prototype.

If you want to change the div's text you should use *div.innerHTML* or *div.innerText*.

Answer (score 0):

`favorite.text('New text')` will set the text

note this will work if using jQuery, my bad!

Comment: I think he is not using `jQuery`

Comment: @user1671639 yes, I realized that after posting it.  apoligies